# awk find lines with two matches

Tags: awk, gawk, mawk

File contains

```
Today is 1 nice day
This is a perfect day
Tomorrow is 1/2 cool 1/2 hot day
What is Toy Story
Tonight is a dark night
```

How do I find lines
starts with "To" and
end with "day"

None of these commands are working

```
awk '/^To[*]day$/ {print}' file

awk '/^To*day$/   {print}' file

awk '/^To.day$/   {print}' file

awk '/^To[.]day$/ {print}' file
```

THANKS!

Comment: Put . In front of * on 2nd example

Answer (score 4):

In regular expressions, `.` matches any character and `*` is a qualifier that you append to something to say *0 or more of that something*. So `.*` is any number (0 or more) of *characters*.

So, like Angelo said, you could do:

```
awk '/^To.*day$/'
```

The beginning of the record (`^`) followed by `To` followed by any number of characters (`.*`) followed by `day` followed by the end of the record (`$`).

Alternatively, you could write it:

```
awk '/^To/ && /day$/'
```

That would also match on records where what's between `To` and `day` contains non-characters. Another difference would be in cases like when you replace `To`/`day` with `abc`/`cde` which would match on `abcde`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$0 ~ /^To.*day$/  {print}' file
```

or just

```
awk '/^To.*day$/  {print}' file
```

or even (as the default action is to print the record):

```
awk '/^To.*day$/' file
```